# Why am I getting 400 Bad Request when trying to delete a role? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
whitelisted_roles = [12345678910, 11121314151617] #example ids

@client.command(aliases=['deleteroles', 'removeroles'])
async def clearroles(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.id in whitelisted_roles:
            pass
        else:
            await role.delete()
```

I've tried changing pass to

```
print(f"{role.id} (whitelisted))
```

and await role.delete() to

```
print(f"{role.id})
```

and it printed out the IDs fine, so I'm not sure why I'm getting "HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50028): Invalid Role" when I try to delete a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping thru all member roles, so they also have to be the @everyone role.
Except it by using `if role.id in whitelisted_roles or role == ctx.guild.default_role` and pass the if-Statement as you're already doing it.